# Datagridview cell decimale fromat during editing in c# window form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]I am creating an application in C# windows form and want to datagridview cell format as decimal like 0.00 during editing in datagridview cell. Given below event is helping me for this purpose but when i editing in new row then this generate an error "Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
event is given below

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        e.Value = d.ToString("0");
    }
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        e.Value = d.ToString("0.00");
    }
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 6 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        e.Value = d.ToString("0.00");
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try Stepping through the code, which line throws the error?

Comment: if (e.ColumnIndex == 5 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        e.Value = d.ToString("0.00");
    }                this line is generating error. or suggest me any other logic which resolve my issue

Comment: Dear Poul Bak error short screen is attached

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double d = (double)e.Value;
```

casting e.value to a double.

This page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.converteventargs.value(v=vs.110).aspx

suggests that that you check the `DesiredType` property before accessing the value:

```
if(e.DesiredType != typeof(string)) return;
```

Comment: this is not helping me following error is received. dditional information: Specified cast is not valid. please suggest any other logic if you have try for this purpose

Answer (score -2):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        e.Value = d.ToString("0");
    }

    else
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        {
            double precio = Convert.ToDouble("0");
            dataGridView1["Column7", e.RowIndex].Value = (precio.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```